# PHP VoltDB Client Library installation

Tags: php, github, compiler-errors, client, voltdb

I'm trying to use PHP and VoltDB together using [these instructions](https://github.com/VoltDB/voltdb-client-php). However, "make" gives me this error, and the compile process fails:

```
root@london:/home/root/voltdb-client-php-extension-5.2/voltdb-client-php# make
/bin/bash /home/root/voltdb-client-php-extension-5.2/voltdb-client-php/libtool --mode=compile g++ -DBOOST_SP_DISABLE_THREADS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -I. -I/home/root/voltdb-client-php-extension-5.2/voltdb-client-php -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/home/root/voltdb-client-php-extension-5.2/voltdb-client-php/include -I/home/root/voltdb-client-php-extension-5.2/voltdb-client-php/main -I/home/root/voltdb-client-php-extension-5.2/voltdb-client-php -I/usr/include/php/20151012 -I/usr/include/php/20151012/main -I/usr/include/php/20151012/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext/date/lib -I/home/root/voltdb/voltdb-cpp/voltdb-client-cpp/include  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g   -c /home/root/voltdb-client-php-extension-5.2/voltdb-client-php/client.cpp -o client.lo
libtool: compile:  g++ -DBOOST_SP_DISABLE_THREADS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -I. -I/home/root/voltdb-client-php-extension-5.2/voltdb-client-php -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/home/root/voltdb-client-php-extension-5.2/voltdb-client-php/include -I/home/root/voltdb-client-php-extension-5.2/voltdb-client-php/main -I/home/root/voltdb-client-php-extension-5.2/voltdb-client-php -I/usr/include/php/20151012 -I/usr/include/php/20151012/main -I/usr/include/php/20151012/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext/date/lib -I/home/root/voltdb/voltdb-cpp/voltdb-client-cpp/include -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -c /home/root/voltdb-client-php-extension-5.2/voltdb-client-php/client.cpp  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/client.o
/home/root/voltdb-client-php-extension-5.2/voltdb-client-php/client.cpp: In constructor âVoltCallback::VoltCallback(int)â:
/home/root/voltdb-client-php-extension-5.2/voltdb-client-php/client.cpp:105:34: error: âzend_list_addrefâ was not declared in this scope
         zend_list_addref(m_res_id);
                                  ^
/home/root/voltdb-client-php-extension-5.2/voltdb-client-php/client.cpp: In member function âvirtual bool VoltCallback::callback(voltdb::InvocationResponse)â:
/home/root/voltdb-client-php-extension-5.2/voltdb-client-php/client.cpp:114:83: error: âzend_list_findâ was not declared in this scope
         voltresponse_res *ptr = (voltresponse_res *)zend_list_find(m_res_id, &type);
                                                                                   ^
/home/root/voltdb-client-php-extension-5.2/voltdb-client-php/client.cpp:126:26: error: invalid conversion from âintâ to âzend_resource* {aka _zend_resource*}â [-fpermissive]
         zend_list_delete(m_res_id);
                          ^
In file included from /usr/include/php/20151012/Zend/zend_API.h:28:0,
                 from /usr/include/php/20151012/main/php.h:40,
                 from /home/root/voltdb-client-php-extension-5.2/voltdb-client-php/client.cpp:25:
/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend/zend_list.h:59:14: note:   initializing argument 1 of âint zend_list_delete(zend_resource*)â
 ZEND_API int zend_list_delete(zend_resource *res);
              ^
/home/root/voltdb-client-php-extension-5.2/voltdb-client-php/client.cpp: At global scope:
/home/root/voltdb-client-php-extension-5.2/voltdb-client-php/client.cpp:134:31: error: variable or field âvoltresponse_freeâ declared void
 static void voltresponse_free(zend_rsrc_list_entry *rsrc TSRMLS_DC)
                               ^
/home/root/voltdb-client-php-extension-5.2/voltdb-client-php/client.cpp:134:31: error: âzend_rsrc_list_entryâ was not declared in this scope
/home/root/voltdb-client-php-extension-5.2/voltdb-client-php/client.cpp:134:53: error: ârsrcâ was not declared in this scope
 static void voltresponse_free(zend_rsrc_list_entry *rsrc TSRMLS_DC)
                                                     ^
Makefile:196: recipe for target 'client.lo' failed
make: *** [client.lo] Error 1
```

I have

- Ubuntu 16.04.3 x64
- installed Boost C++ Library 1.58
- [VoltDB CPP Client Library](https://github.com/VoltDB/voltdb-client-cpp)
- PHP 7.0

Comment: The PHP VoltDB Client Library supports PHP 5.3 and does not yet support PHP 7.0. (I work at VoltDB)

Comment: @BenjaminBallard any chance of getting an estimate on the schedule for the update for the client library? PHP 5 is not in development anymore :-)

Comment: PHP 7 support would be greatly appreciated. In my case, voltdb is no longer an alternative (PHP 5.3 is really really old).